# How to `find` files not being open by any process

Tags: logging, find, cleanup

I have several cron tasks, each of which leaves a separate log file. Successful tasks generate no output, so I'm getting a lot of empty logs.

I'd like to clean it up automatically every day. Requesting `find` to look for size=0 is easy, however I'd like to be sure I'm not removing a log that has been just created by a running task but not closed yet.

Is there a way to tell `find` to skip open files, or I need to resort to `lsof`?

Comment: Assuming your cron tasks complete in less than 24 hours, one simple approach might be to wait and only delete zero-byte files that are more than a day old: `find folderName -empty -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge there is no straightforward way to do it with find.

**Solution One**

Generate a list of open files in the target folder `lsof.lst`. and generate the find list of that folder. then display files in the `find.lst` that are not in the `lsof.lst` list.

to generate the lsof.lst use the following command:

```
lsof +D folderName | awk '{ if(NR>1)print $9 }' | sort | uniq > lsof.lst
```

and then the following command to show the files not currently open in the same folder:

```
find folderName | grep -v -f lsof.ls
```

**Solution Two**

You could also do it in one go like this:

```
find folderName | grep -v -E `lsof +D folderName | awk '{ if(NR>1)print $9 }' | sort | uniq | awk '{print $0}' ORS='|' | sed 's/.$//'`
```

**Explanation**

Now i will try to explain the command so that you can improve it or change it or use the several command line tools in the future.

`find folderName` will generate a list of all files in that folder and subfolders. the output of the find command is piped to `grep` that is here being used with the `-v` switch to exclude the items mentioned in the `-E` parameters from the piped output of the find command. The result will be the output of `find` minus the items mentioned in the `-E` parameter.

The trick here is to generate the list of open files and put it in the  format that `grep -v -E` expects and can work with. grep -E takes a list of strings separated by '|'.

`lsof +D FolderName` will generate the list of open files in that folder, but the list includes a header, and many columns, one of which is the filename, and it could contain duplicates. So we use `awk '{ if(NR>1)print $9 }'` to do two things, remove the first line with `if(NR>1)` and print only the column containing the filename which is with `print $9`. The result is a list of filenames of the open files in that folder without the header.

To remove duplicates, the output is piped to `sort` and then `uniq`, and the next command `awk '{print $0}' ORS='|'` turns the list into a sentence separated by '|', and the last command remove the last '|' as it is excessive.

enclosing that command with the backquotes '`' executes that command in that spot and feeds the output to the`grep -v -E` command.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about `lsof +D`